# Is this transaction serializable?

Tags: database, transactions

Given the following transaction schedule, I have to determine whether it is serializable or not:

```
      T1| T2
-----------------------
    R(A)|
        | R(A)
    R(B)| 
        | W(B)
rollback|
        | W(A)
        | commit
```

The solution to the problem says:
Since T1 read B and T2 writes to B before the end of T1, it is not serializable.

However, the requirement for serializability, as far as I know is:
A serializable schedule over a set S of commited transactions is a schedule whose effect on any consistent database instance is guaranteed to be identical to that of some complete serial schedule over S.

Since T1 only reads and aborts, it does not have any effect on the database instance. So is the solution wrong, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think it depends on the semantics of the diagrams.  The actions under T1 are in time sequence; the actions under T2 are in time sequence; but are the relative positions of the actions in T1 and T2 fixed by the diagram?  If they aren't, then it might be that T1.R(B) occurs after T2.W(B), in which case T1 sees an inconsistent view of the DBMS unless both T1.R(A) and T1.R(B) occur after T2.W(A) — which could happen if the two sides can slide relative to each other. If the relative times of T1.R(B) and T2.W(B) are fixed by the positions on the diagram, then the transaction is serializable.